# Returning characters after regex has found match in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a massive text file that I am searching through to find a small amount of data. Say a part of the string looks like this:

```
'Schedule (1) GEORGE JETSON\n\nPRESIDENT X X 0 O O\n\n(2) BILL CLINTON\n\nVICE PRESIDENT X X 0 0 0\n\n(3)'
```

I need to get the characters between the (1) and (2). My Regex so far looks like this:

```
import re
with open('files/textfile.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    data = myFile.read()
    result = re.search('(Schedule (1).*)', data)
    if result:
        print result.groups()
```

This prints EVERYTHING after Schedule (1). I want to return everything up to the pattern (2). What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: It won't, actually, because the `(..)` part of `(1)` is interpreted as a capturing group and won't match the literal text like that. The `.` meta character will match anything *except* newlines, meaning that the `\n` characters will not be matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a non-greedy match, and switch on the `re.DOTALL` flag to make sure `.` matches newlines:

```
result = re.search(r'Schedule \(1\).*?\(2\)', data, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

The `*?` makes the pattern non-greedy; it'll match up to the *first* `(2)` occurrence in your text; if you use `*` instead the regex will match up to the *last* occurence of `(2)` instead, including any other `(1)...(2)` sections.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = 'Schedule (1) GEORGE JETSON\n\nPRESIDENT X X 0 O O\n\n(2) BILL CLINTON\n\nVICE PRESIDENT X X 0 0 0\n\n(3)'
>>> re.search(r'Schedule \(1\).*?\(2\)', data, flags=re.DOTALL)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107ff5510>
>>> re.search(r'Schedule \(1\).*?\(2\)', data, flags=re.DOTALL).group()
'Schedule (1) GEORGE JETSON\n\nPRESIDENT X X 0 O O\n\n(2)'
```

You can put a capturing group (`(...)`) around the `.*?` to extract *just* the part between the `(1)` start and `(2)` end if you like:

```
>>> re.search(r'Schedule \(1\)(.*?)\(2\)', data, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
' GEORGE JETSON\n\nPRESIDENT X X 0 O O\n\n'
```

Note the `.group(1)` call on the match object.

Comment: Perfect! Now what if I wanted to capture a certain number of characters after the (1), instead of trying to go all the way to the (2)? Say, return the next 25 characters?

Comment: Then use `{25}` instead of `*?`.

Comment: What if I wanted to get the info BEFORE the match case. Same concept, but say I want to get the 25 characters before the match case?

Comment: Then extend your pattern to capture those.

Comment: I recommend you play with your regex at http://regex101.com/ (set the  regex engine to Python). It does a great job at visualizing what your pattern does.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import re

tgt='''\
Schedule (1) GEORGE JETSON

PRESIDENT X X 0 O O

(2) BILL CLINTON

VICE PRESIDENT X X 0 0 0


(3)'''

m=re.search(r'Schedule \(1\)(.*?)\(2\) BILL CLINTON', tgt, re.M | re.S)

print m.group(1)
```

Prints:

```
 GEORGE JETSON

PRESIDENT X X 0 O O
```

Or, if you want to include the beginning and ending markers:

```
print re.search(r'(Schedule \(1\).*\(2\) BILL CLINTON)', tgt, re.M | re.S).group(1)
```

Prints:

```
Schedule (1) GEORGE JETSON

PRESIDENT X X 0 O O

(2) BILL CLINTON
```

If you have a 'massive text file' you may want to use `re.finditer` if you have multiple matches in the file.

If you want to just print a fixed length from a found marker:

```
idx=re.search(r'^\(2\)',tgt, re.M | re.S).start(0)
print tgt[idx:idx+10]
```

Prints

```
(2) BILL C
```

Answer (score 0):

Only captures what you need: `(?<=\(1\))[\s\S]+?(?=\(2\))`